# why egrep doesn't work correctly on AIX?

Tags: regex, linux, grep, aix

I have a simple egrep for searching C/C++ main files(by searching for the main function):

```
egrep '^\s*(int|void)\s+main' *.c*
```

I also have 2 machines one Linux one Aix. On the Linux, this command runs perfectly fine. On the Aix it doesn't - it doesn't return results.Even more, on the Aix the following command does return results:

```
egrep '^\s*(int|void)\s+' *.c*
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Please provide specific inputs that demonstrate the issue.  And let us know what `egrep --version` says on each machine.

Comment: any input would do: 
echo 'int main(' > tmp.c
egrep '^\s*(int|void)\s+main' *.c*
As for the versions: Linux 2.20, as for the Aix - it refuses to give its version(hence why i didn't write it), -v does nothing, --version is considered illegial because of double --.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-GNU `egrep` supplied in AIX apparently doesn't support the '\s' escape sequence, at least according to my test.

Try with the following:

```
egrep '^[ \t]*(int|void)[ \t]+main' *.c*
```

which seems to work for me for the AIX pgrep.

(but still wondering then how `egrep '^\s*(int|void)\s+' *.c*` could work for you as it doesn't seem to work for me)

Comment: Was wondering the same. In anyway this works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: `\s` is just GNU shorthand for the POSIX character class `[:space:]` so the POSIX equivalent of the original regexp would be `egrep '^[[:space:]]*(int|void)[[:space:]]+main' *.c*` to match all spaces, not just blank and tab. The second regexp would match `ints` or `voids` at the start of a line, it would **not** match what the OP wants it to match and note he just says it produces output, not necessarily expected or desirable output. btw `egrep` has been deprecated in favor of `grep -E` for some years now.